# Problem with my Axios route POST using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have a problem with my Post route with axios.
When I clicked on the button to create a new user, I had this error message :
*(node:13901) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined*

I am new with js, node, express etc...

My code :
My react :

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Row, Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_URL } from '../utils/constants';

const Signup = (props) => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    username: '',
    password: ''
  });
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };
  const handleOnSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const { username, password } = state;
      if (username.trim() !== '' && password.trim() !== '') {
/*        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('username', username);
        formData.append('password', password);*/

          setErrorMsg('');
          await axios.post(`${API_URL}/signup`, {
            username: username,
            password: password
          }, {
          });
      } else {
        setErrorMsg("S'il vous plaît entrez un nom d'utilisateur et un mot de passe.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      error.response && setErrorMsg(error.response.data);
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <Row>
           <Col> 
           <Button href="/login">Se connecter</Button>
           </Col>
       </Row> 
      <Form className="search-form" onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
        {errorMsg && <p className="errorMsg">{errorMsg}</p>}
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Form.Group controlId="username">
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="username"
                value={state.username || ''}
                placeholder="Entrez votre nom d'utilisateur"
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Form.Group controlId="password">
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="password"
                value={state.password || ''}
                placeholder="Entrez votre mot de passe"
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          S'incrire
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default Signup;
```

My POST route :

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
//const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../model/user');

router.post('/signup', async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.username);
    try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
//    bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    const user = new User({
        username,
        password,
    });
        await user.save();
        res.send('Votre compte utilisateur a bien été créer.');
} catch(error) {
    res.status(400).send('Erreur lors de la création de votre compte utilisateur. Réessayez plus tard.');
}
},
(error, req, res, next) => {
    if (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
});
```

My user schema :

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema( {
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix my problem, just use "body-parser"

Answer (score 0):

If you use React Hooks, split your different states:

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
```

Comment: Like this ? @Theo Martinez
`const [state, setState] = useState('');
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');
  
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    setUsername({
      ...username,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
    setPassword({
      ...password,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  };
`

Comment: More like this: ```const handleUsernameChange = (event) => {     setUsername(event.target.value); }); ``` for each state. You do not need the classic setState anymore.

Comment: Ok, I changed this but I have always the error message : _(node:30932) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined_

Comment: Have you an idea @Theo Martinez ... ?

Comment: Ok I have fix my problem.
Now I use body-parser